# Como incorporar módulos qml no executável?

Tags: qt

Quando executo um programa feito em `qml` em outra máquina, ele não encontra os módulos do `qtquick`. Imagino que uma alternativa a isso e a incorporação dos módulos no próprio executável. Como devo proceder?

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que mandar as dlls junto do aplicativo para que ele possa ser executado.

Comment: É exatamente o que o Guilherme falou. Se estiver no Windows, o programa Dependency Walker vai ter ajudar. Basta executar o programa a partir do Dependency Walker na máquina sem a Qt, e navegar pelas DLLs para encontrar os módulos que sejam enviados junto. Vale lembrar, que ele apenas detecta os módulos que não são carregados dinamicamente atráves das funções `LoadLibrary` ou `dlopen` (Linux) ou `QLibrary`.

Comment: Já se estiver no Mac, avise que eu posto uma resposta. Passei por isso e pastei até conseguir fazer funcionar.